# Filtering with dplyr not working as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

how are you?
I have the next problem, that is very weird because the task it is very simple.

I want to filter one of my factor variables in R, but the outcome is an empty dataframe.

So my data frame is called "data_2022", if i execute this code:

```
sum(data_2022$CANALDEVENTA=="WEB")
```

The result is 2704800 that is the number of times that this filter is TRUE.

```
a= data_2022 %>% filter(CANALDEVENTA=="WEB")
```

This returns an empty data frame.

I know i am not an expert in R, but i have done the last thing a million times and i never had this error before.

Do you have a clue about whats the problem with this?

Sorry i did not make a reproducible example.

Already thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data with `dput(head(data_2022, 10))`?

Comment: Can you access here? https://github.com/emilianobarone/stackoverflow

Comment: And with `na.,rm = TRUE` for `sum()` ?

Comment: Same result for that code

Answer (score 0):

you could use subset function:

```
a<-subset(data_2022, CANALDEVENTA=="WEB")
```

using tidyverse, make sure you are using the function from dplyr::filter. filter is looking for a logical expression but probably you apply it to a data.frame. Try this code too:

```
my_names<-c("WEB")
a<-dplyr::filter(data_2022, CANALDEVENTA %in% my_names)
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Yes, that works, but do you have any idea of why the above code does not work?

Comment: I edited the answer have look please

Comment: I am trying this code and i still have the same problem: a1= data_2022 %>%  
  dplyr::filter(CANALDEVENTA %in% c("USUARIOSWEB","WEB", "MOBILE")) %>%  
  group_by(USUARIO) %>% summarise(cant=n())